# problem installing geopandas in jupyter notebook using conda

Tags: python, geopandas

I tried installing geopandas in my jupyter notebook using conda.

[image]

I have tried 'pip3 install geopandas'.it got executed but when i try importing geopandas am getting error that

```
no module named geopandas
```

Then I tried `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` where the kernel is getting busy for so long and no getting idle till I restart kernel.

I tried this many times but same thing is repeating.

Comment: Did you restart notebook after installing geopandas?

Comment: Yes but its still the same. I have seen many questions and answers but I haven't seen kernel getting busy for long time till restart.I have followed the below link https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/  .But still am having same problem.